# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python

I don't understand why I'm getting the following error and would appreciate some advice.  Thanks.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    ciphertext = md.encrypt(plaintext)
  File "/Volumes/Mac/Computer/Programming/Cryptography/crypto.py", line 87, in encrypt
    ciphertext = Text()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Code:

```
import crypto

plaintext = crypto.Text('plaintext.txt')
md = crypto.MonomeDinome('fred', 'wilma')
ciphertext = md.encrypt(plaintext)
print ciphertext
```

Crypto.py has the following code:

```
class Text:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.load(filename)

    def load(self, filename):
        fp = open(filename, "r")
        self.rawtext = fp.read()
        fp.close
        self.text = self.convert(self.rawtext)

    def convert(self, txt):
        rval = ""
        for c in txt.upper():
            if c.isalpha():
                rval += c
        return rval

    def set(self, lst):
        self.text = "".join(lst)

    def get(self):
        return self.text

    def __str__(self):
        rval = ""
        pos = 0
        for c in self.text:
            rval += c
            pos += 1
            if pos % 60 == 0:
                rval += '\n'
            elif pos % 5 == 0:
                rval += " "
        return rval

class MonomeDinome:
    def __init__(self, dkw, lkw):
        self.digitsKey = self.digitsScramble(dkw)
        self.lettersKey = self.lettersScramble(lkw)

    def digitsScramble(self, dkw):
        dkl = list((dkw.upper() + "ZZZZZZZZZZ")[0:10])

        for i in "0123456789":
            pos = self.findLowestLetter(dkl)
            if pos != -1:
                dkl[pos] = i

        return "".join(dkl)

    def findLowestLetter(self, lst):
        pos = -1
        lowest = ''

        for i in range(len(lst)):
            if lst[i].isalpha():
                if (lowest == '') or (lst[i] < lowest):
                    lowest = lst[i]
                    pos = i
        return pos

    def lettersScramble(self, lkw):
        rlist = []
        for a in lkw.upper():
            if a == "W":
                a = "V"
            if a == "J":
                a = "I"
            if not a in rlist:
                rlist.append(a)

        for a in "ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ":
            if not a in rlist:
                rlist.append(a)

        return "".join(rlist)

    def __str__(self):
        return "digitsKey = " + self.digitsKey + "\n" + \
                "lettersKey = " + self.lettersKey

    def encrypt(self, plaintext):
        rlist = []
        for char in plaintext.get():
            rlist.append(char)
        ciphertext = Text()
        ciphertext.set(rlist)
        return ciphertext
```

Answer (score 4):

The `filename` argument to the constructor isn't optional, so in `encrypt` this fails:  `ciphertext = Text()`.  It would have to be `... = Text(some_filename)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `Text` to take 0 or 1 option argument.

```
class Text:
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        if filename is not None:
            self.load(filename)
```

---

I believe

```
    ciphertext = Text()
```

makes sense since

```
    ciphertext.set(rlist)
```

is another way of setting `ciphertext.text`, rather than calling the `load` method.

---

By the way, there is also an error in `load`:

```
def load(self, filename):
    ...
    fp.close()   # <--- You need parentheses or else the closed method is not called
```

You could avoid the error by using the `with` syntax:

```
def load(self, filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as fp:
        self.rawtext = fp.read()
    self.text = self.convert(self.rawtext)
```

With the `with` syntax, the filehandle, `fp`, is automatically closed when Python leaves the `with`-suite.